# Contrasts for distributional parameters in a shifted log normal distrbution

Tags: bayesian, lognormal-distribution, contrasts, lsmeans, psychology

I’m playing around with shifted log normal distributions in [brms](https://paul-buerkner.github.io/brms/index.html) (for reaction time data), trying to get my head around the parameter estimates and also how to do contrasts with them using the emmeans package (which from brms v2.13 and later, has its own emmeans support [according to the documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/models.html#S). The output of the model is as below,

[image: Model summary output]

Now, the Intercept value makes sense as exp(5.21) gives 183 ms. Similarly, the ndt_Intercept makes sense too as exp(5.05) gives 156 ms. But, the sigma_Intercept doesn’t make sense as exp(-0.97) because 0.38 ms is highly improbable, but it does make sense as exp(5.21-0.97), which gives 69.4 ms. My questions are as follows then,

1. Is the above understanding of sigma_Intercept as exp(5.21-0.97) correct?
2. If so, is there a way to re-parameterize the model such that the sigma_Intercept estimate outputs 4.24 (5.21-0.97) directly as this would make it a lot easier to use `emmeans(model_fit, pairwise ~ factor, dpar = "sigma")`. Currently, it picks up only the -0.97…
3. On a slightly related note, the summary of the model_fit tells us that the mu parameter has an identity link function. Given this, the `type = "response"` argument for the emmeans function doesn’t exponentiate the estimates (and doesn’t give a ratio for the contrasts). This is a small point and I know I can do this myself but I was wondering if there was a way to do this? (**solved by Russ' code in the comment below**).

Thank you for reading.

**UPDATE** - For anyone wanting to know more please see a discussion on the [Stan Discourse forums](https://discourse.mc-stan.org/t/contrasts-for-distributional-parameters-in-a-shifted-log-normal-distrbution/17535)

Comment: I am surprised it didn't detect the log transform, but you can compensate by doing `rg <- update(ref_grid(model_fit), tran = "log")` and then use `emmeans` on `rg`.

Comment: That worked perfectly @RussLenth, thank you!

I was surprised too but the `summary(model_fit)` outputs a log link for the sigma and ndt parameters (for which `type = "response"` argument in `emmeans` works as intended) and identity for the mu parameter, so I am guessing `emmeans` uses that information rather than deducing that the mu parameter is already log transformed given that a lognormal distribution is used?